# ADB doesn't detect my android tablet in ubuntu?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, adb, udev

I want to run my android apps in my tablet directly from eclipse. I set up my device as per the procedure given in android site added rules files with correct vendor ID. But it didn't work.

even the adb devices command didn't detect my device.
so what is the problem ? I search throughout the site and apply all the answer.

PS : my tablet is not belong to a big brand

Comment: Have you tried to restart adb?

Comment: yes adb kill-server and start-server

Comment: yes by using chmod a+r...  like command

Comment: Nono, sudo `sudo service udev restart`

Comment: ok I did that pa1pal@Pa1:~$ sudo service udev restart
[sudo] password for pa1pal: 
udev stop/waiting
udev start/running, process 4763